# Understanding LaTeX packages syntax

Tags: macros, catcodes

I've been using LaTeX for a few years for typesetting maths documents but I kind of feel there are two "kinds" of latex: the one I write my documents in and the one packages are written.

My goal is not to write a package, but trying to solve problems by my own. I often find myself searching for solutions to every problem I face and the answers always involve this syntax I'm talking about, full of `@`s, and things like `\expandafter`, `\makeatletter`, `\makeatother`, `\catcode`. Since I can't understant it, I simply copy it blindly.

What's the recommended resources for learning this not-so-basic latex stuff?

Comment: I wrote a book, in order to learn (part of) it. It's in Italian, so it may not be what you're looking for.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) I'd recommend [this book](http://www.eijkhout.net/tbt/) which covers plain TeX.

Comment: I checked http://profs.scienze.univr.it/~gregorio/introtex.pdf and I guess that's what I was looking for, but unfortunately I can't speak italian. But I'll take a look at the references later, thanks

Comment: Much of this has been covered in other answers on the site: trying to explain everything in a single answer is really too much to expect. For example, you might look at [What do \makeatletter and \makeatother do?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/what-do-makeatletter-and-makeatother-do) to get some feel for `\makeatletter`. The usual recommendations (_The TeXbook_ and _TeX by Topic_) almost always apply when looking at programming TeX.

Answer (score 2):

Read the TeXbook.  You have to pay for it, but it's worth it: not only is it totally complete (even more so than TeX By Topic, recommended by mafp in the comments) but it is an instruction manual rather than a reference manual.  It has one drawback: it documents the plain TeX format in addition to the actual base TeX language, and completely disregards LaTeX and other formats (as it rightfully should).  Unfortunately, it makes no clear distinction between what is a built-in feature of TeX and what is defined by the format, whereas TBT does (by not addressing the format at all).  In practice, this means that you should skim the main text once and then focus on the dangerous bend stuff, which is the reference material.

I have heard complaints that the TeXbook is too chatty or written with a poor style.  The fact that it has a style at all does open it up to such criticisms, but also makes it possible for it to interface with the reader on an intuitive level.  If your intuition differs from Knuth's, there is no shame, but TeX is an outrageously difficult language to understand so it may help to appreciate the slightly eccentric mind of its creator.

Comment: Then, for LaTeX, one has to read the documented source `source2e.pdf`

Comment: @egreg: As a reference, yes.  But it's not very well-written.  I think the `exam` document class is very nicely constructed and may (as just one example) provide a better introduction.

Answer (score 0):

LaTeX2e is very difficult to program in; I suggest you use the experimental versions of the LaTeX3 format. To load it, all you need is

```
\usepackage{expl3}
```

and documentation is available with `texdoc expl3` and `texdoc source3`.